# bootstrap top level menu items don't link on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

On this page: franklincc.info/migrate the top menu items that have submenu items don't go to the pages they're supposed to go to when clicked. However, if you right-click on the item, like About the Chamber, and click Load in another tab, then the link works. Submenu items work fine. Home link  works fine.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Quite frankly, they aren't supposed to. This is a well known "issue". Many people complain about it, but that is literally the default behavior. It's supposed to be an action to trigger the dropdown.

This might help you: http://wpeden.com/tipsntuts/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-and-activating-click-event-on-parent-item/ (check the comments too)

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

}, function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

});

$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
location.href = this.href;
});

});
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you are using different code for the mobile view, you can remove the `data-toggle="dropdown"` instance and include the CSS code to make the sub nav appear on hover instead of click to allow the parent to be clickable. (see http://brianjosephstudios.com/php-tutorials/web-design-tip-how-to-make-the-parent-link-item-clickable-in-twitter-bootstrap/) for solution.

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    margin: 0
}

a.menu:after, .dropdown-toggle:after {
  content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my tests works fine in Firefox 30 for Ubuntu .. maybe you fixed
but you must check

li element doesn't get open class on hover. Just on click "About the Chamber".